# She visiting (?) my house, I was studying English

Tags: sentence-construction, participles, progressive-aspect

I felt this sentence that uses participial construction is unnatural but I don't know why.

> She visiting my house, I was studying English.

Is that because of the verb, visit? I'm non-native speaker.

Comment: I'd like to know about the participial construction in this sentence so I'd like you to teach me about that particularly.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the present progressive tense, the "to be" verb is required.

> She was visiting my house.

As written these two actions are *disconnected*.  If you want to connect them in some way you need to *relate* them to each other, for example:

> She was visiting my house while I was studying English.
>
> She was visiting my house after I finished studying English.
>
> She came to visit me as I was studying English.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! so maybe it's useless to use participial construction in this kind of sentence?

Comment: For example, Can I change this sentence into the participial construction one? When she was visiting my house, I was studying English.

Comment: @02l4  Yes, exactly.  That helps relate the two actions.  However the present progressive tense indicates *ongoing* action, but "when" suggests a single moment in time, so here the simple past is better "When she visited my house, I was studying English."